# React fetch to Express API not working, any tips?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am trying to make a simple fetch call to my express API and I can't get it to work, the response is 200 but I get an the index.html instead of the JSON I want. This is my scenario:

package.json

```json
"version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application to show FrontEnd knowledge",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
```

react component code

```
  callBackendAPI = () => {
    const body = fetch("/api/hello")
    .then(res => res.text())          // convert to plain text
    .then(text => console.log(text))  // then log it out

    return body;re
  };
```

express server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})

// create a GET route
app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
  });



  // console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Just tried your example and it works for me, something else has to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From your server code, it looks like you're sending back JSON, but in your frontend code you're looking for text.

```
 callBackendAPI = () => {
    const body = fetch("/api/hello")
    .then(res => res.json())         
    .then(data => console.log(data.express))
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a proxy setting in your `package.json` to redirect requests from the React development server to your Express API server. However, the issue might be related to the way you are making the fetch call in your React component.

Firstly, make sure you are making the fetch call relative to the root of your React application, and not to an absolute path. In your `callBackendAPI` function, update the fetch call as follows:

```js
callBackendAPI = () => {
  const body = fetch("/api/hello")
    .then(res => res.json())          // parse response as JSON
    .then(data => console.log(data))  // then log it out

  return body;
};
```

Here, I've changed `res.text()` to `res.json()` to parse the response as JSON since your Express route is sending a JSON object.

Additionally, you might want to handle errors in your fetch call. Modify your function to include error handling:

```js
callBackendAPI = () => {
  return fetch("/api/hello")
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
};
```

With these changes, you should be able to fetch the JSON response from your Express API. Make sure that your React development server is running and your Express server is also running on the specified port. If you still encounter issues, check the browser's console for any error messages.